# How to create a SKSpriteNode that is the circumference of a circle, just the outline?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, uibezierpath, skspritenode

I want to create an `SKSpriteNode` as described above. I have tried `UIBezierPath`, but *XCode* did not recognize the functions for creating an object of that type. I think I may have to `import` something, but I'm unsure as to what.
When I implement the following,
I get the error: `Missing argument in call: center`

However, once I add the appropriate argument,
I get the error: `Extra argument 'edgeLoopFromPath' in call`.

My code is below:

```
let circlePath: UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPointMake(self.frame.midX, self.frame.midY), radius: self.frame.height / 2, startAngle: 0, endAngle: 360, clockwise: true)
let confinCircle: SKPhysicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(center: CGPointMake(self.frame.midX, self.frame.midY), edgeLoopFromPath: circlePath)
```

Comment: You should post the code you tried to use to create a UIBezierPath

Comment: @AbhiBeckert The code is up, along with error messages.

Comment: check the skphysicsbody class reference or let xcode auto completion guide you, it looks like you got the parameters in wrong order, edgeLoopFromPath should be the first param afaik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my solution:

```
 let circlePath: UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPointMake(self.frame.midX, self.frame.midY), radius: self.frame.height / 2, startAngle: 0, endAngle: 360, clockwise: true)
 confiningCircle.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeChainFromPath: circlePath.CGPath)
 self.addChild(confiningCircle)
```

Interestingly, the name of the parameter "edgeChainFromPath" differs from the name of the parameter [Apple lists on their official class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKPhysicsBody/bodyWithEdgeChainFromPath:): 
On the website, they call it `bodyWithEdgeChainFromPath`, which is different from the working code above.

Answer (score 4):

I feel like you're making things hard using paths and all that.  You want a circle that is just a line with no color on the inside.
Try this:

```
let circle = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 10)

circle.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 10)

circle.fillColor = SKColor.clearColor()
circle.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width/2, y: self.size.height/2)
self.addChild(circle)
```

Comment: sure but shape nodes are slow

Comment: I need a physics body.

Comment: I fixed my problem, and I'll post the answer in a second, but I need the physics body to be hollow as well. I found something close to a solution here: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKPhysicsBody/bodyWithEdgeChainFromPath: